# Issue Unhiding div Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Have successfully setup a menu which cycles between multiple tabs using Javascript. The issue is I'm using SiteLevel as a search for this site. I want the search box to be a part of the hide/unhide menu but the script (I've also tried the html code for the search box, but still no fix)

I've paired it down to the simplest form of this concept to ensure that it's not some other css or script that's conflicting, but it still opens to a blank box here's the code.

I've pumped it into http://jsfiddle.net/Split98/A3DVa/

```
<a href="#software">Software</a>
<a href="#hardware">Hardware</a>
<a href="#supplies">Supplies</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#search">Search</a>
<div id="nav">
    <div id="software">Hello!</div>
    <div id="hardware">Yes!</div>
    <div id="supplies">Yeee Haw!</div>
    <div id="contact">Bingo!</div>
    <div id="search"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sitelevel.com/javabox?crid=ze32uipb"></script></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav div {
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
   var divs = $('#nav div'),
   links = $('a');

   links.click(function () {
       $(this.hash).toggle().siblings().hide();
       return false;
   });
})
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Not sure I get it? What's a "blank box", and what are you expecting ?

Comment: @adeneo he's expecting the search box when you click on the "Search" tab

Comment: @ExplosionPills - Oh, how strange! First thing I did was just to set the first tab to visible, and everything seemed to work just fine, did'nt check the search tab before, but see now that it's not working. However, this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3DVa/4/) works for me?

Comment: Correct Explosion Pills. As it stands now, the red box should have a search box in it (<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.sitelevel.com/javabox?crid=ze32uipb"></script>) but the script remains hidden.

Outside of the hidden divs, the box shows up fine:
http://agiile.com/testing6.html

Comment: Does the fiddle in my comment above work for you ?

Comment: And adeno, that works for me too, I just need them to be hidden by default on first load

Comment: Here's a [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/A3DVa/5/) with a hackish solution.

Comment: Works! Thanks a ton bud!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/A3DVa/6/)**</kbd>

Simply use `#nav > div` in your CSS
Will target only the immediate childrens.
Otherwise all `DIV` elements will be hidden (your search tool)

```
#nav > div {
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
    height: 200px;
}
```

edited jQuery

```
$(function () {       

    var divs = $('#nav div'),
        links = $('a');

    divs.eq(0).show(); // if you need it.....

    links.click(function ( e ) {  // e = event
        e.preventDefault();       // instead of return false;
        $(this.hash).toggle().siblings().hide();
    });
});
```